# Is there a more elegant way to collapse a variable with 88 levels to one with 5 levels?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a categorical variable with 88 levels (counties) and I want to aggregate those into five larger geographical regions. Is there a more elegant way to do this than a huge amount of ifelse statements (like below)?

```
survey.responses$admin<-ifelse(survey.responses$CNTY=="Lake","Northeast",
                         ifelse(survey.responses$CNTY=="Traverse","Northwest", 
                         ifelse(survey.responses$CNTY=="Ramsey","Central",
                         ifelse(survey.responses$CNTY=="Cottonwood","South","out of state")
```

except imagine that CNTY has 88 levels! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Two quick methods, I recommend the `merge` one for larger sets.

Data

```r
dat <- data.frame(cnty = c("Lake", "Traverse", "Ramsey", "Cottonwood"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

1. **Merge/join**. I prefer this for several reasons, most of all that it is quite easy to maintain a CSV of the matches and `read.csv` the CSV into the `ref` lookup table. I'll intentionally leave "Lake" out to show what happens with non-matches.

   ```r
   ref <- data.frame(cnty = c("Cottonwood", "Ramsey", "Traverse", "SomeOther"),
                     admin = c("South", "Central", "Northwest", "NeverNeverLand"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   out <- merge(dat, ref, by = "cnty", all.x = TRUE)
   out
   #         cnty     admin
   # 1 Cottonwood     South
   # 2       Lake      <NA>
   # 3     Ramsey   Central
   # 4   Traverse Northwest
   ```

   The default value is assigned in this way:

   ```r
   out$admin[is.na(out$admin)] <- "out of state"
   out
   #         cnty        admin
   # 1 Cottonwood        South
   # 2       Lake out of state
   # 3     Ramsey      Central
   # 4   Traverse    Northwest
   ```

   If you're using other components of `tidyverse`, this can be done with

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   left_join(dat, ref, by = "cnty") %>%
     mutate(admin = if_else(is.na(admin), "out of state", admin))
   ```
2. **Lookup**. This works fine for small things, perhaps not best for your fit. (Again, I've commented "Lake" out to show the non-match.)

   ```r
   c(Cottonwood="South", # Lake="Northeast",
     Ramsey="Central", Traverse="Northwest")[dat$cnty]
   #        <NA>    Traverse      Ramsey  Cottonwood 
   #          NA "Northwest"   "Central"     "South"
   ```

Comment: I've tried both the merge command and the left_join command with no luck. I think the issue is that my dataset as over 600 rows while the reference table has 87 rows. How do I get the reference to apply to all of the rows? EDIT: to clarify, the merge command runs, but all of the entries for "admin" are NA and it is not correctly categorizing the counties

Comment: R seems to think my cnty variable is an integer even after as.factor()-ing it multiple times in multiple ways...could this be contributing to my issue?

Comment: `as.factor` internally generates integers from common strings. The 600-vs-87 row thing is not a problem; you can merge 10-v-10, 10M-v-3, etc. One problem with joins/merges is that when there are `factor`s involved (and the frames' factors' levels were generated separately), then matches are not found. One workaround is to convert all factors to string with `as.character` (both frames, columns in the `by=` argument), then join. Then if you want them to be factors again, just re-`factor` them.

Comment: Okay, so I figured out what the issue was...there are a bunch of white spaces/hidden characters in my County names in my dataset so it wasn't recognizing them. I've tried using `strip.white=TRUE` but the white spaces persist.

Comment: You might need an explicit call to `trimws`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some pattern in `CNTY` which you can combine and create some logic on you need to include those levels manually. One way would be to use `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

survey.responses %>%
  mutate(admin = case_when(CNTY %in% c("Lake","Northeast") ~ "GR1", 
                           CNTY %in% c("Traverse","Northwest") ~ "GR2", 
                           CNTY %in% c("Ramsey","Central") ~ "GR3", 
                           TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```